# Auto span row with same content (php/mysql/jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I'm showing data from mysql in to a webpage table.
Code (I'm working on wordpress) :

```
    global $wpdb;
    $Lists = $wpdb->get_results("select * from `price_record`;");
    if($Lists== null)
    {
        echo"There is no price record yet!";
    } 
   else
   {
        echo"<table class='priceTable' style='border:1px;border-collapse:collapse;'>";
            echo"<thead>";
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<th>Date</th>";
                    echo"<th>Category</th>";
                    echo"<th>Type</th>";
                    echo"<th>Price</th>";
                echo"</tr>";
            echo"</thead>";
            echo"<tbody>";
            foreach ($Lists as $List) 
            {
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$List->Date."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$List->Category."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$List->Type."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".number_format($List->Price,2)."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            }
            echo"</tbody>";
        echo"</table>";
    }
```

Current result:

```
Date    Category    Type    Price   
---------------------------------  
30/1    A           T1      12     
30/1    A           T2      13     
30/1    B           T3      10      
30/1    B           T4      11      
29/1    A           T1      11
```

Expected:

```
Date    Category    Type    Price   
---------------------------------
30/1    A           T1      12     
                    T2      13     
        B           T3      10      
                    T4      11      
29/1    A           T1      11
```

How can I autometically group the date, category and type when showing the table?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us the code you've been working on or the structure of your database, (is it just one table or is it joined by a table to another, etc.).

Comment: just show us your php code that generate this output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should make it. Note that the `ORDER BY` in the sql query is important.

```
 global $wpdb;
    $Lists = $wpdb->get_results("select * from `price_record` ORDER BY Date DESC;");
    if($Lists== null)
    {
        echo"There is no price record yet!";
    } 
   else
   {
        // Initiate dateElement
        $dateElement = '';

        echo"<table class='priceTable' style='border:1px;border-collapse:collapse;'>";
            echo"<thead>";
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<th>Date</th>";
                    echo"<th>Category</th>";
                    echo"<th>Type</th>";
                    echo"<th>Price</th>";
                echo"</tr>";
            echo"</thead>";
            echo"<tbody>";
            foreach ($Lists as $List) 
            {

                if($List->Date == $dateElement) {

                  // If existing day, show a blank td
                  $dateElement = '&nbsp;';
                } else {

                  // If new day, reset categoryElement and set the dateElement to the new day
                  $categoryElement = '';
                  $dateElement = $List->Date;
                }

            // If same category (and same day), show a blank td, otherwise show the category
            $categoryElement = ($List->Category == $categoryElement) ? '&nbsp;' : $List->Category;

             echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$dateElement."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$categoryElement."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$List->Type."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".number_format($List->Price,2)."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            }
            echo"</tbody>";
    echo"</table>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this almost fit! Can it span the row that have the same date?